# Canoo / Ant properties scoping differently in tasks and steps?

Tags: ant, properties, canoo

We have a Canoo webtest set up to test a multi-locale application. For each locale, the webtest loads a number of properties from a properties file.

In the example below, locale_code, htaccess.username, htaccess.password and webtest_url are all defined in such a property file.

In the webtest task itself, ${locale_code} is replaced, resulting in (for example)
"CatalogueOrderFriendsCountry DE-DE http://www.example.com".

The properties in the invoke step, however, are not replaced, with the description showing up as "Einstieg Hauptseite ${webtest_url}" *even though they are properly replaced just one line above it*.

```
<project default="test">
  <import file="../../definitions.xml"/>
  <target name="test" depends="wt.defineMacros">
    <webtest name="CatalogueOrderFriendsCountry ${locale_code} ${webtest_url}">

      <invoke username="${htaccess.username}" password="${htaccess.password}" url="${webtest_url}" description="Einstieg Hauptseite ${webtest_url}"/>
      ...
```

It is pretty obvious that the locale specific properties file is loaded, we can change webtest_url (for example) in the file and the new value is properly replaced in the webtest name.

I know next to nothing about ant (Canoo being my exposure to it), and very little about Canoo webtest (I recently inherited them), so I'm not even sure whether this is a webtest or an ant issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using Ant 1.8
Dynamic properties are not evaluated.
You have to use Ant 1.7

See issue [Dynamic property resolution does not work with Ant 1.8 or later](http://webtest-community.canoo.com/jira/browse/WT-569)
or [Canoo Webtest Mailing List](http://lists.canoo.com/pipermail/webtest/2010q3/013347.html)